# Can i link a css to only one react component?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I want to apply one CSS file to only on Home.js component. I don't want this CSS to be applied to other components. For other components, I have a CSS file. But when I apply that CSS file to Home.js, it also applies to other components, and it mixes everything.

Comment: I would recommend you to make a unique id name for each element in home.js and apply CSS through that id name.

Comment: i was thinking if there is any way that i can apply a css file to only one component but anyways that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a css file is loaded it is accessible in all files. If you need to avoid the style being conflicted, it would be better to create a unique id/class name or use inline styling

Comment: thanks. i have used unique ids to fix it.